# Booting a Live USB ISO as an Alternate OS

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, iso

I recently fixed a virus-laden Windows laptop for a teenage niece, but I am sure she will gum it up again. Unfortunately, she isn't ready to make the plunge to Ubuntu, but I thought an accessible live version would be a great way for her to still have basic functionality when Windows will no longer function.

Could I do something like put the Live USB ISO on a separate ext4 partition and add it as a boot entry? Any help on how to do that in the most user-friendly way possible would be appreciated. The machine will be running Windows 10 with a EFI boot process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @Ron I don't think this is a duplicate, as the OP asks for a life system (even though a simple dual boot would probably be a better idea).

Comment: @Bruni To me, putting a live usb iso on a separate ext4 partition is a long version of dual-boot ;)

Comment: I can tell you how to achieve this with ubuntu - I COULD tell you as well how to do this on Windows, but this is an ubuntu support platform. So decide to install ubuntu OS or ask this on a Windows forum.

Comment: Just FYI (in case someone comes along who has an answer to this) I wanted to do a live system as opposed to a dual boot so that the linux system would be refreshed to a pristine state at every boot.

I figured that way no amount on mucking on the part of the niece would make the system unusable.